# How can get object from a list<> with a int index?

Tags: c#, list

How can get object from a list<> with a int index?

```
List<BasicLow> _list = new List<BasicLow>();

int positionInList=0; //for example from position zero!

BasicLow aux = new BasicLow();

aux = _list.**WHAT I PUT HERE?**
```

Thanks!

EDIT

Thanks but i try this(aux = _list[positionInlist];)! give me a error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

But i has assurance the positionInlist exist on _list!

Comment: Is the same as Array, I'm surprised. This demonstrated you haven't readed anything about Collections in .Net, is a very low quality question, this is not the place to this question. Go to google and search for "c# collections" and you will get a lot of info about how to accessing items in collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
aux = _list[positionInList];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
aux = _list[positionInList];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
BasicLow aux = _list[positionInList];
```

Note: there is no point in initializing to a new object if you are going to immediately replace with the results of a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
aux = _list[positionInList];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_list[positionInList]
```

Will give you The object

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows nothing being placed in the list. And if the list is empty, then there is no index that is a valid index.